# php raw socket on tcp

Tags: php, sockets

***Php supports raw socket on tcp(6)?***

```
$socket  = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, getprotobyname("tcp"));
```

I tried this.But,I got a warning message.

> Warning: socket_create(): Unable to create socket [10013]: An attempt was made to 
>   access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.

I tried with ICMP(1).It is working.

```
$socket  = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, getprotobyname("icmp"));
```

or other way to send a tcp syn packet in php?

Comment: Raw sockets are probably restricted to root access. There's one comment about that in the docs https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-create.php

Comment: But,socket on icmp is working.Do you know a solution?

Comment: I don't know. Are you running this on a Unix/Linux system or on Windows which might have different access rules?

Comment: I am running this on xampp apache server on windows. ICMP is working.<?php
$host="127.0.0.1";
$package = "\x08\x00\x4d\x2e\x00\x01\x00\x2dabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwabcdefghi";
    $socket  = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, getprotobyname("icmp"));
    socket_sendto($socket, $package, strLen($package),0,$host,getprotobyname("icmp"));
    $output=socket_read($socket, 255);
    echo $output."<br>";
    socket_close($socket);
  


?>